# Do I manually have to set framework paths in Xcode 11.5?

Tags: xcode

I have a custom framework that I want to use in my Xcode project. I can easily add it to my project by clicking the "+" button in "Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content" and then choosing "Add Other...".

However, when I try to build my project, Xcode complains that it can't find the framework. This doesn't surprise because apparently Xcode doesn't pass the framework's path to the linker. The path to the framework is `/Users/Andreas/TestFramework`. As you can see, this path isn't passed to `ld` by Xcode at all:

```
Ld /Users/andreas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-csdbiydhibfjqcdvbmzzinqjghgj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyApp.build/Release-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Binary/MyApp normal x86_64 (in target 'MyApp' from project 'MyApp')
    cd /Users/andreas/Documents/MyApp
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -target x86_64-apple-ios8.0-simulator -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.5.sdk -L/Users/andreas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-csdbiydhibfjqcdvbmzzinqjghgj/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator -F/Users/andreas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-csdbiydhibfjqcdvbmzzinqjghgj/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/andreas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-csdbiydhibfjqcdvbmzzinqjghgj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyApp.build/Release-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MyApp.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/andreas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-csdbiydhibfjqcdvbmzzinqjghgj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyApp.build/Release-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MyApp_lto.o -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/andreas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-csdbiydhibfjqcdvbmzzinqjghgj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyApp.build/Release-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/MyApp.app-Simulated.xcent -framework TestFramework -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/andreas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-csdbiydhibfjqcdvbmzzinqjghgj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyApp.build/Release-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MyApp_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/andreas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-csdbiydhibfjqcdvbmzzinqjghgj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyApp.build/Release-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Binary/MyApp

ld: framework not found TestFramework
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I know I could probably easily fix this by just adding the framework's path somewhere in the build options but does Xcode really require this?

Having to add the path for every custom framework I use would be quite a hassle. Xcode could do this really easily automatically. So is it really necessary to explicitly add the path to the framework to my Xcode project or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I was able to solve this issue by copying the custom frameworks needed by my app to my app's project directory. Then the error went away.

It's possible to have Xcode do this automatically by drag'n'dropping the custom frameworks to the `Frameworks` section of my Xcode project and then selecting `Copy items if needed` in the ensuing Xcode dialog.